# Laravel View returns un-wanted and different data from Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Everybody, my code below returns Tasks that have more than 1 Tag and 
and the code is working fine until I pass it to View. It then returns all of the tasks, even the tasks that have only one tag.

My Code

```
$posts = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q)  {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q){
        $q->has('tasktags', '=' , 2)->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])
->where('id','>',1)->get();
```

My View

```
return view ('task',compact('posts'));

@foreach ($posts as $Task)
<h2>{{ $Task->name }}</h2>

@foreach ($Task->pathtags as $Tag)
<h3>{{ $Tag->name }}</h3>

@foreach ($Tag->tasks as $Ta)
<h2>{{ $Ta->task_name }}</h2>

@endforeach

@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: So when you dump the contents of `$posts` in the controller, it has the correct data?

Comment: yes When I use dd($posts) i get correct data

Comment: Can you show the complete code for this controller method?

Comment: it's in the top  it is the first code My friend

Comment: Is there anything else between fetching the results and passing them to the view? You have the line where you return the view in the same section where you have your actual view code, so we can't see if there is anything else going on in the controller.

Comment: no nothing this code and return view no more